Waiting for a MySQL or MariaDB server to become ready to perform updates
Is there an universal command/query to issue at the mysql client program to wait for the server to become ready for processing queries and updates, independent of whether the server is MySQL or MariaDB, local or remote, clustered or not, and independent of a particular database server version ?
This one should, for instance, wait until a mariadb-upgrade is finished, or, if Galera is used, wait until a State Transfer (IST or SST) is complete, or for any other procedures which occur automatically on server startup and which are of a temporary nature, that is, where waiting is a useful action for the client.
I would use that wait-to-become-ready-command in the startup script of an application in order to prevent from errors to occur because the application starts before the database is ready. If there is no universal command or query, please point to individual solutions for any of the above situations, which I would have to combine to produce a solution as universal as possible.
Edit (clarification): This question is targeted to situations where the mysql client is able to successfully connect to the database server but errors occur if some SQL is issued. Only in this case it is possible to issue any command/query which I'm seeking here. I was able to connect while, for instance, mariadb-upgrade was  still running, but issuing a grant statement caused the still running mariadb-upgrade process to crash.
So if the connection attempt is successful, it may or may not mean the server is ready to handle queries and, equally important, it may or may not mean the server is ready to process updates.

There isn't a single universal command for this purpose, but you can create a small script that repeatedly tries to connect to the server using the mysql client. If the connection attempt is successful, it means the server is ready to handle queries. If the attempt fails, the script should wait a little while and try again. Keep doing this until you're able to connect, indicating that the server is fully ready.
Example:
 #!/bin/bash

# Replace these variables with your actual database credentials
USER="your_username"
PASSWORD="your_password"
HOST="your_database_host"
DATABASE="your_database_name"

# Loop until the connection is successful
until mysql -u"$USER" -p"$PASSWORD" -h"$HOST" -e "USE $DATABASE"; do
  echo "Database is not up yet. Waiting..."
  sleep 5 # wait for 5 seconds before check again
done

echo "Database is up and ready to take queries!"

